# Pi 3 problem, any suggestion?

Tags: pi-3

I was wondering if someone could help me out. Seems a simple thing to do but I am lost. I bought a Pi 3 because I wanted to do retro gaming. I can't seem to get it going. Anything I download I am unable to open or run it. I just get a pop-up asking me to Choose and Application to open an 'unknown' file. Don't know what to do and very frustrating!

Comment: What OS do you have on your RPi3 and can you give an example of something you downloaded?

Comment: Is this about RetroPie?
 https://retropie.org.uk/ I recommend using their pre-built OS image then.

Comment: I think this should be prominently displayed somewhere on the site: https://youtu.be/53zkBvL4ZB4

Comment: You need to make an effort to describe your problem in more detail.  You have left it up to the people you are asking for help to guess about what software you are referring to, where you got the SD card, what is on the SD card, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that you are downloading files to a Windows PC and trying to run them as Windows programs.  What you need to do is to create an SDcard for the PI and run the Pi.  There is a good guide here https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/2/ on how to get started with the simplest of methods using the Noobs download to get an operating system onto the Pi.  You can either purchase a pre-loaded sdcard with the noobs software or you can download noobs and copy the files to a suitable card.  With a noobs card created and a keyboard, mouse and monitor connected to the Pi.  Insert the noobs sdcard in the sdcard slot and plug in the power supply - then follow the remainder of the guide linked above to get started with your Pi.  Once you understand how that works you can look into more specialised operating system configs like retropie etc...